# Mozart/Oz : convert string to feature

Tags: record, oz, mozart

I need to generate features names that I don't know in advance, in order to make a record.
The record should look like:
`record(day1:[...] day2:[...] day3:[...] ...)`.
As I don't know how many days the record will contain, I cannot write features names by myself! 
I tried several things:

```
{For 1 N 1
proc {$ I}
  local 
    Label 
    Day="day"
  in
    ...
    % Label=Day+I 
    % cannot add a list and a number

    % Label={List.append Day {Int.toString I}} 
    % creates the right string, but when trying to make the record: type error

    % Label=dayI 
    % works but produces only "dayI" features, all the same

    % Label=day + I
    % cannot add a feature and a number
    ...
  end
end
}
```

All Labels are then processed in a list, in order to use `Record.makeTuple`.

Is there any way to create dynamic features, or manipulate them?
For now, the only alternative I found is to use the string, not as a feature but with a pair : 
`record("day1"#[..] "day2"#[..] ...)` but this is not what I want.

Thanks for any answer or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features of records are atoms. To convert a string to an atom, use `String.toAtom`. For example:

```
declare
L = {String.toAtom "dynamic string"}
R = {MakeRecord record [L]}
{Show R}
```

However, if I remember correctly, there is a caveat: atoms are not garbage-collected. If you create very many different atoms, you might run into memory problems.

Comment: You just saved my life. 
Actually, I also tried to convert the string to atom, it didn't work.  
The real problem is that I'm a moron that apparently cannot read error logs: 
I was trying to use `MakeRecord` with the spec of `AdjoinList`. Of course Oz complained that he expected a "feature list" while I passed `[day1#content1 day2#content2 ...]`. 
Anyway thank you, now my program is both good working AND good looking :)